# How to connect to a mysql remote server using node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, selenium-webdriver, phpmyadmin

Am trying to connect to a Mysql remote server using nodejs + selenium-webdriver.

The host am trying to connect is this: [phpmyadmin.locaweb.com.br](http://phpmyadmin.locaweb.com.br)

If you acess this site, you will be able to see 3 fields to complete: Server,
User and Pass.

In my code, i do not know how to include the "Server". Looking in the [web](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), i found the "localAdress" to pass as connection option, but is not working. 
What i got so far:

```
//DB - config
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  connectionLimit : 10,
    host: "phpmyadmin.locaweb.com.br",
    localAddress: "*****.mysql.dbaas.com.br",
    user: "******",
    password: "******",
    port: 3306,
    database: "*****"
});

con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});
```

Error:

```
Error connecting to Db
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:425:13)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\node_modul
es\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\node_modu
les\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\node_modu
les\mysql\lib\Connection.js:136:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\status.js
:17:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you connect to the actual database server.  Phpmyadmin is just a web server that makes calls to your database.  If you have access to Phpmyadmin it will have the database details in there.

Comment: Well, you´re right. Instead of using the phpmyadmin link as the localAdress i was using as host. Thank you!